# Symfony2 (.7) : Users in firewall with active directory

Tags: php, symfony, silex, adldap

I searched for this kind of connection but all the bundles do not work with symfony security 2.7 (Composer says packages problems) and symfony 3.0.

*Note : I actually use Silex Framework.*

I want to return a true or false response if the user is connected to the active directory.

I have this code for tests :

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'login' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/login$',
        ),        
        'secured' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'anonymous' => false,
            'logout' => true,
            'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
            'users' => array(
                // raw password is foo
                'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

The login with admin & foo worked but that's not what I want.
I want to replace this part of code :

```
'users' => array(
    // raw password is foo
    'admin' => array('ROLE_ADMIN', '5FZ2Z8QIkA7UTZ4BYkoC+GsReLf569mSKDsfods6LYQ8t+a8EW9oaircfMpmaLbPBh4FOBiiFyLfuZmTSUwzZg=='),
),
```

Or any others solutions to replace the value who allows the user to bypass the firewall and enter in the application.

Note :
I use adLDAP plugin to test the connection with the Active Directory (It's works perfectly).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `LdapUserProvider` for it. Remove `'users' => array(...)` from `secured` config and add user provider definition for this zone.

```
$app['security.user_provider.secured'] = $app->share(function($app) {
    return new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\LdapUserProvider(
        new \Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient('ldap.server.com'),
        'baseDn', // ex.: dc=example,dc=com
        'searchDn' // ex.: CN={username},DC=example,DC=com
    );
});
```

Or you can write your own user provider based on `LdapUserProvider` and `adLDAP`. Something like this:

```
namespace My\Namespace;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\LdapUserProvider;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;

class adLdapUserProvider extends LdapUserProvider
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        // you code, that returns user from ldap server
        // $this->ldap - is object of adLDAP
        $user = $this->ldap->user()->info($username);

        return $this->loadUser($username, $user);
    }
}
```

and change user provider definition

```
$app['security.user_provider.secured'] = $app->share(function($app) {
    return new \My\Namespace\adLdapUserProvider(
        new \adLDAP\adLDAP(...)
    );
});
```

Comment: Now, I have the following error : ` ldap_search(): Search: Operations error`

Comment: Show parameters that are used for `LdapUserProvider` and `adLDAP`

Comment: Here it is : [...] ` ( new \Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient('srv-ad-01.domd1232.com'),
        'dc=domd1232,dc=com',
        'CN={username},DC=domd1232,DC=com'
    ); ` I tried without the CN, but still the same

Comment: May be password is required. Try to compare LdapUserProvider and adLDAP parameters. LdapUserProvider contructor interface is `(LdapClientInterface $ldap, $baseDn, $searchDn = null, $searchPassword = null, array $defaultRoles = array(), $uidKey = 'sAMAccountName', $filter = '({uid_key}={username})')`

Comment: I have hardcoded my credentials in Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient class but it still says "Bad Credentials." or I get some other errors. I've found the ldap_search() function in this class return an array with "'count' => 0". I also have copy / pasted the filters, etc who was in adLDAP classes but still the same errors.

Comment: I've changed my answer with another variant

Comment: Sorry, I tried my best but after few test it show errors like "Bad Credentials." or "Warning: null given (to encode the password)". I also implemented user interfaces, ldapInterfaces that it request but I gonna loose myself. I don't know how it works but thanks for your answer.